# Mongoose query condition inside a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am not sure how to make the title of this question a bit more clear :)

So let me jump directly to the schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  _events: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Event" }]
});
```

Basically a user can have a number of events that are referenced by another model, Event. The event collection looks like this:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  _userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  eventDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  instructions: String,
});
```

I am doing a query on Mongoose that lists all the events created by the user, as follows:

```
  app.get("/api/events/", requireAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const userEvents = await User.findById(req.user._id)
        .populate({
          path: "_events",
          model: "Event",
          })
        .select({ _events: 1 })
        .exec();
      res.send(userEvents);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });
```

This works perfectly. However I am interested in listing only future events. How can I modify the query to do a condition where `eventDate` > current date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query for that in the populate function as follows:

Here:

```
.populate({
  path: "_events",
  model: "Event",
})
```

Add this:

```
match: { eventDate: { $gte: Date.now() } }
```